# Foreach loop through cpt categories to use ACF values

Tags: ajax, wordpress, if-statement, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

I am looping through my CPT categories and I want to use my ACF field inside my for each loop.

```
 <div id="response">
         <?php
         $args = array(
          'post_type'  => 'segments-overview',
           'orderby' => 'date', // we will sort posts by date
           'posts_per_page' => -1
        );



        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        $all_terms = [];
        if( $query->have_posts() ) :
          while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();

          $terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'category-segments-overview');
          foreach($terms as $term) $all_terms[$term->term_id] = $term;

          endwhile;

          foreach($terms as $term):
            ?>

          <div class="segments-card">
            <div class="img">image</div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="title"><?php echo $term->name; ?></div>
                
                // ACF field
                <?php echo the_field('product', $term->taxonomy) ; ?>

                <a class="button transparent" href="/segments/<?php echo $term->slug; ?>">
                <?php echo __('View All','axia'); ?>
              </a>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        <?php endforeach;

          wp_reset_postdata();
        else :
          ?>
          <div class="no-posts-found">
            <h2>There were no items found</h2>
              <h3>Please try a different search</h3>
          </div>
          <?php
        endif;
          ?>
    </div>
```

Can anyone tell me how to retrieve my value of my "products" field inside the foreach loop.
For now i do not recieve any errors, but i also do not recieve any value.

please help.

Comment: `echo get_field('product', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id);`

Comment: The answer below is an actual answer, where the person used time on helping you - I just threw out 1 possible answer - Give him the credits needed for his work - Glad that I could help though - I am not really suppossed to answer questions in a comment :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to learn documentation about field for taxonomy terms:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/

In your case you can just replace

```php
echo the_field('product', $term->taxonomy);
```

by (3 possibilities)

```php
echo the_field('product', $term);
// or
echo the_field('product', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id);
// or
echo the_field('product',  'term_' . $term->term_id);
```

### How to load a field from a specific term ?

Basically load field from acf is : `get_field('key', $post_id)`

For taxonomy terms there are 3 different styles of `$post_id` available and are listed below. (this is from acf documentation)

```
+----------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Example        | Format                     | Description                                                                 |
+----------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 'category_123' | $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id | A string containing the taxonomy name and term ID                           |
+----------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 'term_123'     | 'term_' . $term_id         | 'term_' . $term_id                                                          |
|                |                            | A string containing the word ‘term’ and term ID. Added in version 5.5.0     |
+----------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| WP_Term        | $term                      | A term object. You can get a term object via many of WP’s functions such as |
|                |                            |                                                                             |
|                |                            | get_term()                                                                  |
+----------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Have my upvote - Sorry for "answering in a comment"